# Ошибка в запросе. Как обработать названия с одной кавычкой

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос для MySql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM software WHERE idPC='35' AND name='Seagull's Music' GROUP BY name;
```

Но он ругается, из-за одинарной кавычки `Seagull's Music`. Как обрабатывать подобное, если `Seagull's Music` подставляется программно.

Comment: Вряд ли дело происходит в консоли. А из клиента лучше использовать параметры (parameters binding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте двойной апостроф:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM software
WHERE idPC='35' AND name='Seagull''s Music'
GROUP BY name
```

[Пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2a6c2/3/0).

Answer (score 0):

Экранируйте кавычки обратной косой чертой:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM software 
WHERE idPC=\'35\' AND name=\'Seagull\'s Music\' GROUP BY name;
```